# undefined method `test_get_index' for class `Minitest::Result'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara, minitest

I'm trying to run this integration test. For some reason, it isn't accepting minitest syntax and I have no clue why.

test_helper.rb

```
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require "rails/test_help"
require "minitest/rails"
require 'minitest/reporters'
require "minitest/rails/capybara"

Minitest::Reporters.use!

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
    fixtures :all
end
```

gemfile.rb

```
group :test do
    gem "minitest-rails"
    gem 'minitest-rails-capybara'
    gem 'minitest-reporters'
    gem 'guard'
    gem 'guard-minitest'
    gem "selenium-webdriver"
    gem "chromedriver-helper"
    gem "shoulda-matchers", require: false
end
```

integration_controller_test

```
require 'test_helper'

class MovieControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
    setup do 
        @movie = movies(:movie_1)
    end

    describe "integration testing" do
        test 'get index' do 
            get movies_path
            assert_response :success
        end     
    end
end
```

Comment: Try removing the `describe` line.

Comment: I managed to get it to work but I have another problem. I have to directly specify the file when I run it 'ruby -Itest test/controllers/test_movies_integration.rb'.

Comment: If I type 'rails test', no tests are located and everything goes green. 0 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips.

Comment: Where are your test files located?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/cb6z3wj

Comment: As in the image above, where they are located by default.

Comment: Try renaming your file to whatever_test.rb

Comment: that seems to of fixed it!